# How do I filter multiple tags with the same word in them?

Tags: discussion, support

I have times when I care less about Adobe-related tags such as `adobe-photoshop`, `adobe-illustrator`, `adobe-fireworks`, `adobe-indesign`, `adobe-acrobat`, or `adobe-flash`. It would be useful if I could turn the noise out by filtering out things with label `adobe`.

Is there anyway to filter or tune the questions listed on the front page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "adobe*" to your ignored tags (to the right of the main questions list).

If your ignored tags are just dimmed and not hidden, update your [user prefs](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/4169) and check the "hide ignored tags" box.

Comment: I still see them.

Comment: @hhh Updated.  Keep in mind that you must spell "adobe" correctly if you want to filter "adobe" tags.